# leiningen how to specify dependency for clojure without duplicating jar

Tags: clojure, leiningen

Everytime I do a lein new  I seem to get a copy of the clojure jar in the lib folder of that project. I thought that jars deps were copied to .m2/repository. Why is the clojure jar duplicated for every lein project?

Answer (score 1):

This only happens with Leiningen 1. The reason for this (I think) was to allow tools to inspect the dependencies easily. With Leiningen 2, this is no longer an issue because it uses the [pomegranate](https://github.com/cemerick/pomegranate) library (which is a wrapper for Aether) to manage dependencies. It allows for more robust dependency management, and therefore Leiningen can just link to the dependencies from your local Maven repository.

Answer (score 0):

Jars are cached in your .m2 repo.  However, to use them in your project, they need to be on your project's classpath, usually in your project/lib directory.  Caching in your local Maven repo just saves you a download from the server.